# Difference between unsigned and unsigned int in C

Tags: c, int, unsigned

Could you please make it clear what the difference is between `unsigned` and `unsigned int`?  Maybe some example code would be helpful.

Comment: Try this code: `unsigned int a=-1; printf("see as signed=%d\nsee as unsigned=%u\n", a, a);`

Answer (score 77, accepted):

`unsigned` is a modifier which can apply to any integral type (`char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, etc.) but on its own it is identical to `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 15):

There is no difference. `unsigned` and `unsigned int` are both synonyms for the same type (the unsigned version of the `int` type).

Answer (score 11):

`unsigned` alone means unsigned int.  You can also use `unsigned char`, etc. I have no idea what happens if you try `unsigned double` or `unsigned float`.  Anybody know?

Comment: The compiler will tell you that's an error. Both `double` and `float` are defined through IEEE-754 documentation.

Comment: @stan that makes sense. I was imagining the weird behavior that would occur if somehow `double` and `float` could be unsigned. Would it just ignore the sign bit? Maybe add a bit of precision to the significand or something?

Comment: @Daniel: 6.2.5 in [the C99 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) is a good read. Basically it says there are floating types and integer types; and `unsigned` does not match any part of the specification of floating types :)

Comment: @Stan: C permits `float`, `double`, and `long double` to be implemented as specified by IEEE 754, but it doesn't require it.

Answer (score 4):

unsigned indicates that it's unsigned int. So they are equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

They are exactly the same thing.