# Difference between unsigned and unsigned int in C++

Tags: c++, types, int, unsigned

What is the difference between `unsigned` and `unsigned int`?

This question was already answered for C (there is no difference):

[Difference between unsigned and unsigned int in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176657/difference-between-unsigned-and-unsigned-int-in-c)

I am interested in knowing whether there is any practical difference in C++.  Are they the same type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between unsigned and unsigned int in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176657/difference-between-unsigned-and-unsigned-int-in-c)

Comment: I wouldn't vote for closing. `C` != `C++`.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

They are the same type, as in C. No differences at all.

Of course, `unsigned` can be used as a qualifier for other integral types. But by default, `unsigned` is the same as `unsigned int`.