# Is there a difference between unsigned and unsigned int

Tags: c, unsigned, unsigned-integer

In C, is there a difference between `unsigned` as a type directly and `unsigned int`?

Update:
This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176657/difference-between-unsigned-and-unsigned-int-in-c), but the other question didn't answer about small subleties that can exist. Thanks @EOF for pointing out the implementation defined behavior in bitfields.

Comment: No, the types are the same.

Comment: So no small subleties there?

Comment: No, it's like `short` vs `short int` or `long` vs `long int`: `int` is optional when qualified.

Comment: @FSMaxB See C11 draft standard n1570: *5 Each of the comma-separated multisets designates the same type, except that for bit-
fields, it is implementation-defined whether the specifier int designates the same type as
signed int or the same type as unsigned int.* So the only subtlety is about bitfields.

Comment: @EOF Exactly these kinds of subleties is what I wanted to know. Although I hope that no compiler actually implements these differently in bitfields.

Comment: @FSMaxB: Compilers *absolutely* use different signedness for bitfields of declared type `int`. It's one of the canonical examples of implementation-defined behavior encountered in the real world. For example, an `int i:1` in a struct can be initialized as `.i = 1;` and consequently compare *unequal* to one: `.i != 1` is true. It can also compare *equal* when the program is compiled with a different compiler or for a different target.

Answer (score 0):

No, `unsigned` and `unsigned int` both refer to the same type. See [**cppreference/fundamental types**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)**:**

[image: cppreference screenshot]

Comment: Did you create this list, or where does it come from? As it stand this is the default to assume. Did you make your it isn't copyrighted before posting it here to the world?

Comment: @alk: I thought that *"See cppreference/fundamental_types:"* was enough to understand that the list was coming from cppreference/fundamental types. The caption also says "cppreference screenshot".

Comment: For licensing, see [cppreference/FAQ](http://en.cppreference.com/w/Cppreference:FAQ)

Comment: "*For licensing*" Thank you. This is good to know.