# Short unsigned int in C++

Tags: c++, class, short

So in my exam in the class I was supposed to declare X as a short unsigned. I declared it short unsigned int X. Is this way still OK and correct? Thank you

Comment: It goes for all built-in integral types, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7176690/14624729).

Comment: You can declare it as `unsigned short X`

Comment: These are all the same, which to use is a matter of *style*:  `short unsigned`, `unsigned short`, `int short unsigned`, `short int unsigned`, `short unsigned int`, `int unsigned short`, `unsigned int short`, `unsigned short int`

Comment: Reminder:  most of the integer types are based on range, not bitwidth.  For example, I could have a 32-bit processor that uses a 32-bit value for `char` or `short`, and still be compatible with the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `short unsigned int` and `short unsigned` are exactly the same type.

Personally I prefer `unsigned short` for readability.

See for yourself by testing

```
std::is_same<short unsigned int, short unsigned>::value
```

Comment: `short` is short for `short int`